# Why is my std::filesystem-using SO exposing the std::filesystem symbols?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, nm

I am building a shared library on Linux, and have configured the project to compile with `-fvisibility=hidden` and with `__attribute__ (( __visibility__ ("default")))` manually added to the symbols I want to export. The following dummy file is sufficient to illustrate:

```cpp
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

__attribute__((__visibility__("default"))) void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }

void bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }

// void baz() { std::cout << fs::current_path().string() << std::endl; }
```

Then build with:

```sh
g++ -shared -o dummy.so -fPIC dummy.cpp -lstdc++fs -fvisibility=hidden
```

and run `nm -CD dummy.so | grep " T "` to check the exported symbols (those defined in the text section, per the man page).

- As-is, you'll see just `foo` exported: this is what I expected.
- If you remove `-fvisibility=hidden`, you'll see `foo` and `bar` both exported. Also expected.
- If you uncomment `baz` (a function that uses std::filesystem), you'll see tons of filesystem symbols exported, whether or not you have `-fvisibility=hidden`. Something like this:

```
000000000003b110 T std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_iterator::operator*() const
000000000003a930 T std::filesystem::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::depth() const
000000000003a980 T std::filesystem::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::operator*() const
0000000000034bb0 T std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::parent_path() const
0000000000032870 T std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::has_filename() const
```

and so on - showing only symbols that are in std::filesystem or std::experimental::filesystem.

Looking at the libstdc++ `fs_path.h` header, I'm assuming this visibility is triggered by the `namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)` line. However, filesystem isn't the only standard library facility used in the library (the real one or this dummy one): lots of others are used too, and none of them show up in this view.

I understand why those symbols should be visible when the actual standard library SO is being compiled, but why are they being "exported" from my library that only consumes the standard library? And, why are only the filesystem symbols being exported? Can I fix this without removing my std::filesystem use?

(My environment is Debian Buster x64. This appears to happen regardless of whether I use Clang or GCC, and the system compiler is GCC 8.3.0 with its associated libstdc++.)

Comment: I don't believe that you can get around this. If some other library or executable linked to yours needed that library then it would want to find the symbols. I believe your only other option is to do a static link and use `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL`

Comment: Hmm. Those symbols are for internal-use only (and are actually header-only template things). I'd expect anything linking to get their own copy of them, which is perhaps a mental error since it sounds like ODR-violation, but it's strange that only std::filesystem does this.